# Same random number each day php

Tags: php, random

I want to display a quote of the day by finding the id of the post, so I'm using the seeds as the lowest and highest ids, so each day I get a random id, this will display a random post each day.
I am using this to generate the same random number each day:

```
mt_srand(crc32(date('D d F Y')));
echo $random = (mt_rand(1,8288));
```

This worked perfectly on php version 5.3 or lower however on one of my other servers which is version 5.4.33. It doesn't work and always creates a new one each time. I have changed php versions to test this and it seems that it is the version that affects it.
Is there another way to generate a 'consistent random' number each day? I need a number so that I can query the database and show a particular post per day.

I don't want to create another table or add another row to add dates for each post because that'll mean I have to create future dates for each post and there are already too many rows to do that.

Comment: if the number just represents the date. why not just use the date?

Comment: @Dagon I need a number between the seeds. I'll update the question. Thanks

Comment: populate the db with the date. seems like you are going out of your way to make this far more difficult than need be

Comment: @Dagon can't populate it with date, in that case I will need future dates for each post to display.

Comment: to much missing information ,but its clearly more verbose than needed.

Comment: last comment. daily unique id: `echo date('dmY');` wrap it in a hash function to change its look or size if that floats your boat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A peek at the [PHP manual for mt_srand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-srand.php) tells you this:

> The Mersenne Twister implementation in PHP now uses a new seeding
>   algorithm by Richard Wagner. Identical seeds no longer produce the
>   same sequence of values they did in previous versions. This behavior
>   is not expected to change again, but it is considered unsafe to rely
>   upon it nonetheless.

So what you need to do is to use the "bad old" **srand** and **rand**-functions. They will produce the result that you are after.

I'd like to add a final note: do NOT use these  functions (or mt_rand for that matter) for anything security-related [as stated here](http://www.codeaddiction.net/articles/9/cryptographically-secure-random-numbers-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

If you need a daily ID, the easiest approach that comes to my mind is:

```
$today_code = substr( date("D") , 0,1) .  substr( date("j") * date("Y") , 0, $your_desidered_lenght = 2);
```

This will produce an ID in the format = A12, where "A" is the first letter of the week and "12" is an integer that will be produced for the whole current day. This tecnique  ID is:

- As code, easy to read
- As output, somehow readable. You can surely know in which day of the week was created.
- easy and flexible to customise